# How to reset dynamodb local data for unit testing

Tags: jestjs, serverless, amazon-dynamodb-local

using Jest, DynamoDB Local, I wanna reset database for each test so it doesn't have to be in specific order.
Is there any way to do that wisely?

```
beforeEach(() => {
 resetDB()
})

it('create a data', () => {

})

it('remove the data', () => {

})

it('find the data', () => {
 test should pass but it fails because the data is removed.
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I would look into [@shelf/jest-dynamodb](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/dynamodb) to get started.

I wrote a [testing library](https://github.com/erezrokah/aws-testing-library) for AWS services, but it uses the real DyanmoDB and not the local version.
You could try using the code [here](https://github.com/erezrokah/aws-testing-library/blob/fd043a0054ef5b3a936d3c8cffec4341c49e43e1/src/utils/dynamoDb.ts#L14) to delete all items from a table.